# need my animaiton to run continously until stopped, and not started over even on susequent call

Tags: swift

I have the following animation. This works well however if image.flash is called in an if statement or a loop, the animation starts over and looks very unsmooth.

I need a way to allow the first call to the flash function to continue until stopped.
even if the function is called subsequent times.

```
extension UIView {
        func flash() {
            self.alpha = 0;
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0,
            options: [.curveEaseInOut, .autoreverse, .repeat],
            animations: { [weak self] in self?.alpha = 1.0 })
        }
    
        func stopFlash() {
            layer.removeAllAnimations()
            alpha = 0
        }
    }
```

Comment: So add a boolean flag `animationIsRunning`. Set it to true in `flash()`, and to false in `stopFlash()`. At the very beginning of `flash()` check if it's true. If it is, exit. Note that you won't be able to do this from an extension since they can't add instance variables to classes. I'd need to know more about your use-case to suggest a way around that limitation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. 
The flash function is being called from some if statements inside a CLLocationManagerDelegate
if this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if view is already in the middle of animation, to don't repeat your animation like using guard so before you add new animation remove previous ones.

```
        func flash() {
            // check if self is in the middle of view or containing an specific of animation
            guard self.layer.animationKeys() == nil else { return }
            
            self.alpha = 0;
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0,
            options: [.curveEaseInOut, .autoreverse, .repeat],
            animations: { [weak self] in
                self?.alpha = 1.0
                print(self?.layer.animationKeys()) // print type of animation
            })
        }
```